# How to set font to be DejaVu Sans Mono in vim for xp?

Tags: vim

i have installed vim for xp ,there is a file `_vimrc`in  C:\Vim ,i have set font in `_vimrc` :

```
set guifont=Bitstream_Vera_Sans_Mono:h11:cANSI
```

when i open vim ,the setup can not work ,when i open gvim ,the setup can work .
what is the matter?
the configuration i write in _vimrc can work perfectly in gvim when i open it ,why it can not work in vim?
In my gvim and cmd ,i can see  Bitstream_Vera_Sans_Mono font in screen ,and my active console code page is set to be 437, vim can't use Bitstream_Vera_Sans_Mono font ,why?

Comment: If you set the font with the GUI like in the picture, you can see exactly what you need to type by using `:set guifont?`.

Answer (score 9):

In [`$MYVIMRC`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#_vimrc), add the line:

```
set guifont=DejaVu\ Sans\ Mono:h11
```

...where `:h11`, specifies a height of 11 points.

N.B: A `_` can be used in the place of a space, so you don't need to use
      backslashes to escape the spaces.

#### Reference

- [`:help 'guifont'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27guifont%27)

#### Notes, following update to question

[`'guifont'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27guifont%27) only works on [Vim's GUI](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui.html#GUI) (*i.e.*  `gvim`) and not on a console (or terminal) `vim` instance. Vim has no control over the font of the terminal in which it is running.

If you wish to change the Windows XP([!](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/endofsupport.aspx)) [console font](http://www.wikihow.com/Customize-the-Font-in-Windows-Command-Prompt), see [How to change the Windows XP console font?](https://superuser.com/q/5035/37904) on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).